# Navbar logo won't work in CSS but will work in HTML

Tags: html, css

Trying to fit an image to the navbar I'm using. I can not get it to work in CSS but I can get it to work in HTML. I do not want to style the logo in HTML, only in CSS.
The image is "RPGWizards.jp"
This is the html

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#"><img src="Assets/RPGWizards.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="OurProducts.html">Our Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

This is the CSS

```
#logo{
    width= 42px ;
    height= 42px;
    }
```

[image]/NTqjn.jpg

Comment: Try #logo img{
width:80%;
}

Comment: It worked, but it's off center.

Answer (score 1):

You have used is an incorrect syntax for `width: 48px;` there is colon in between not `=` symbol.

> The class `nav-brand` has a padding and you need to make it to `0` and fit it to the block.
>
> View in full screen for visualization.

```css
a#logo.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
}

#logo img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 51px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="OurProducts.html">Our Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]